# Cockroachdb storage increasing without any reason

Tags: storage, cockroachdb

I am using cockroachDB for storing the login credentials of the users. I only have one table with no records in it. But I noticed that the cluster storage is increasing slowly without any activity in database. Why is it happening? How do I stop this ?[yesterday's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22glb.png)

[Today's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUejc.png)

Answer (score 0):

A CockroachDB cluster will regularly store information about its own health and status in system tables, so that it is available to you should you need it (e.g. in your dashboard). Once these tables hit their retention limit, storage will level off. Overall, however, the amount of stored system data should be very small in relation to overall limits. For example, in this case, 3MB is only 0.06% of the free storage limit.